# How to implement `push_back()` function on LinkedList?

Tags: data-structures, rust, linked-list

I have started learning rust a few days ago. I had heard that implementing Data Structures in rust are pretty confusable though I wanted to give it a try. The choice fell on the simplest LinkedList.

I implemented a `Node` as a struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

Without a generic value, for simplicity.

I implemented `fmt::Display` in order to write tests, and a simple `new` function for node creation.

```rust
impl fmt::Display for Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}

impl Node {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Node {
        Node {
            value,
            next: None,
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a `LinkedList` struct that holds the head and the tail.

```rust
struct LinkedList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
    tail: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

For now, I only tried to implement `push_back()` function and it turned out to be hard enough for me to fail.

It is the current state of it:

```rust
impl LinkedList {
    pub fn push_back(&mut self, value: i32) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node::new(value));

        match self.tail {
            Some(ref mut tail) => {
                tail.next = Some(new_node.clone());
                swap(&mut Some(new_node.clone()), &mut self.tail);
            }
            None => {
                self.head = Some(new_node.clone());
                self.tail = Some(new_node.clone());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before I show the results of it, let me explain how do I understand my code - which is where most likely the error occurs.

I create an immutable pointer to the newly created node. Pointer - `Box` - is stored on the stack and points to the node created on the heap.

Then I match `self.tail` to see if the list is empty. In such a case I execute this block of code:

```rust
self.head = Some(new_node.clone());
self.tail = Some(new_node.clone());
```

So I'm deluding myself that `self.head` and `self.tail` points to the same address on the heap, because I only clone the pointer. If I understand my debugger properly, it - unfortunately - ain't the case.

If I naively execute it on the empty list, it compiles and assigns some Node to the tail. When I try to add another node, the first arm executes:

```rust
tail.next = Some(new_node.clone());
swap(&mut Some(new_node.clone()), &mut self.tail);
```

Here, I want to operate on the tail, which should be the exact same node as the head, and modify its `next` property. Afterward, I try to swap the current tail, with the newly created node.

Thus, on this state, I would expect my LinkedList to look like that:

```
Head: Node { value: 5, next: Node { value: 3, next: None } }
Tail: Node { value: 3, next: None }
```

My code doesn't meet my expectations though.

It outputs:

```
Head: Node { value: 5, next: None }
Tail: Node { value: 3, next: None }
```

What do I misunderstand? I'd be grateful for any hints.

If someone wants to reproduce the code, I also share the code I wrote that is responsible for tests.

```rust
fn scan_list(list: &LinkedList) -> impl Iterator<Item=Node> {
    let mut current_node = list.head.clone();

    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        match current_node.clone() {
            None => {
                None
            }
            Some(node) => {
                current_node = node.clone().next;
                Some(node.as_ref().clone())
            }
        }
    })
}
```

*tests.rs*

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use expect_test::{expect, Expect};
    use crate::{scan_list, LinkedList, Node};

    fn test_list(src: &LinkedList, expect: Expect) {
        let actual: String = scan_list(src).map(|node| format!("{:?}\n", node)).collect();
        expect.assert_eq(&actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_empty_list() {
        let list = LinkedList { head: None, tail: None };
        test_list(
            &list,
            expect![r#""#],
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_list_with_single_node() {
        let list = LinkedList { head: Some(Box::new(Node::new(5))), tail: None };
        test_list(
            &list,
            expect![r#"
                 Node { value: 5, next: None }
            "#],
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_list_with_two_nodes() {
        let mut list = LinkedList { head: None, tail: None };
        list.push_back(5);
        list.push_back(3);
        test_list(
            &list,
            expect![r#"
                 Node { value: 5, next: Node { value: 3, next: None } }
                 Node { value: 3, next: None }
            "#],
        )
    }

}
```

It of course doesn't pass the last one.

Comment: Step 0: don't try to learn rust by making a linked list. No additional Step required. Over. https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Box` is a smart pointer. When you clone a `Box`, it creates a deep copy, not a shallow copy, and the nodes will be entirely different in memory ([the implementation is here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.63.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1289-1335), if you want to take a look).

Moreover, what you are trying to do *is impossible in Rust*. You're trying to violate Rust's core borrowing rule: there are no aliasing mutable borrows. You try to alias `head` with `tail` when the list is empty, and `tail` with `tail_prev.next` when not. I guess you started with a simple code without all those clones, but the compiler complained so you added them. You just hid the problem, but solved nothing.

There are three different approach to solve that. The first and most recommended for you is to stop trying to fool the compiler. Just don't alias. Create a singly-linked-list with only `head` and no `tail`. This is something you should be able to solve on your own.

The second and third are more complex. The first of them being to use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). The last and most dangerous is to use unsafe code (this is what [`std::collections::LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) does, but it is not recommended for beginners, especially without advice).

A very recommended reading if you want to create linked lists to learn Rust is [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). It implements all the three variants and more.

Comment: Thank you , it answers all of my questions. I did implement it without a tail properly, but I wanted to extend it. I've read about Rc And RefCell yesterday, but wasn't sure how to use them here. I will definitely play more with them and try to use it. If I will struggle again I will refer to the implementations you linked